# No history, left and right in Python3 Interactive Shell(Debian)?

Tags: python-3.x, debian

Hello I am using Python3 in my Debian Squeeze 6. However, I am not been able to access histories and take advantage of left and right arrows. I see these characters when I press left right up and down. [[A^[[B^[[B^[[C^[[D. I don't have problem in default Python2.6 interpreter. How do I fix this?
P.S I open interpreter as python3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the readline library before compiling Python.

Comment: @BinitaMaharjan sudo apt-get install libreadline-dev probably does the trick, but I'm not on debian, so I don't know 100%. See also: askubuntu.com/questions/21547/what-are-the-packages-libraries-i-should-install-before-compiling-python-from-so

Comment: @BinitaMaharjan How id you install Python 3 and what version?

Answer (score 2):

On Python 3.4  :

```
sudo python -m pip install readline
```

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest you install Ipython? It has quite a number of history and interactive tools for python. http://ipython.org/

Comment: Good answer, but you could also explain why command-line editing doesn't work the way the poster assumed.